# Does $(x+ay+bz+c)^2+(x+dy+ez+f)^2$ have a minimum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-regression

Consider a function $g:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$g(x,y,z)=(x+ay+bz+c)^2+(x+dy+ez+f)^2.$$
Here, $a$, $b$, $\cdots$, $f$ are real numbers.
Does $g$ has minimum?
(i.e. How can I ensure the existence of the minimum of the function?)

*My trial* :
I originally thought that $g$ is a quadratic form and tried to check the positive definiteness.
But it is not a quadratic form as it stand.

(The motivation for this problem is the linear regression.
I wondered why $\text{SS}_{\text{reg}}=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(y^{(i)}-f(x^{(i)})\right)^2$ has a minimum value where $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ is a linear (an affine) function $f(x)=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\cdots+\beta_dx_d$ and where $\text{SS}_{\text{reg}}$ can be thought of as a function of $\beta_i$'s.)

Comment: Hint: (1) is the function non-negative? (2) Can it take value zero?

Comment: @StasVolkov Oh, you mean the minimum value is zero. And it is indeed, as you hinted. That is to solve the system of linear equations x+ay+bz+c=0, x+dy+ez+f=0, which always have a solution. The existence of the solution is due to the fact that the number of (free) variables exeeds the number of equations, so I should have add more squared terms (at least four terms in total) to make this problem nontrivial. lol

Comment: Can I edit the original problem? or delete it and make a new one?

Comment: not so fast! if $g(x,y,z) =x^2 + (x+1)^2$, $0$ is not the minimum...

Comment: @peterag Oh right. In that case, $0$ can not be the minimum.

Comment: So the first comment of mine is wrong. The system of linear equation either has infinitely many solution (and the minimum is zero) or has no solution.

Comment: @govindah In 'my' example, $g$ attains a minimum of $1/2$ at $x=-1/2$.